# How to freeze columns from the back using wijmo flex grid?

Tags: wijmo, frozen-columns, wijmo-grid

Flex Grid in Wijmo has **frozenColumns** property. 
This property is usually used to froze columns from before. 
How to freeze columns from the back using **frozenColumns**?

Answer (score 1):

The FlexGrid columns can be frozen from left only.
To freeze column from right, you need to create multi pane grids as given below sample.
https://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/p8hw2a3v